# how to make the controller redirect results to an outside link or return a script alert in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to make a validation here in my table there is a column to store the data in the form of url to another link.

Here I want to make validation if the data exists then it will point to the link in `$ get-> url_drive`

if it's not there then I want to display it in the form of a script for the user and redirect back this my controller

```
$id   = $request->input('id');
$type = $request->input('type');
$name = $request->input('name');

$type = strtolower($type);
$name = strtolower($name);

$get  = DB::table('users.user_connects')->where([

        [ 'user_id' , $id ],
        [ 'type' , $type ],
        [ 'name' , $name ]

    ])->first();

if(isset($get)){
 // here i am confused
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(isset($get)){
    return redirect($get->url_drive)
}else{
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', ['your message,here']);;
}
```

redirect back **blade file**.

```
@if (\Session::has('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul>
            <li>{!! \Session::get('error') !!}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```